# tcpdump expression syntax error in `ip proto tcp`

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I scrutinized the man pages of tcpdump and pcap-filter (which dictates the grammar of tcpdump's expression), but I could not find why my expression is error:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i lo 'ip proto tcp'
tcpdump: syntax error
```

The man page clearly spells out `ip proto protocol` is valid grammar: https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html

Could the issue be a version mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like tcpdump doesn't understand the `tcp` alias in that context. You'll need to use the actual IP protocol number:

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo ip proto 0x6
```

---

If you want IPv6 as well (which is what `tcpdump -i lo tcp` translates to):

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo ip proto 0x6 or ip6 proto 0x6
```